# Why "Error: ENIVAL: invalid argument, mkdir" is happening when I run npm

Tags: npm

I was trying to install react but an ***EPERM*** error occurred so in order to remove that I cleared my cache and I edited the prefix just like it was shown in the youtube tutorial but now whenever I use npm in a command ***ENIVAL: invalid argument, mkdir error*** is showing. Can anyone please tell me how to remove it.

```
Error: ENIVAL: invalid argument, mkdir `C:\Users\Duke LoVeR\`C:\Users\DuKeLoVeR\AppData\Roaming\npm``
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCh1U.png)

Comment: Which tutorial? And could you please copy the actual text into your question using `code`, so that the search engines will properly index it?

Comment: I don't know. I have gone through a lot of tutorials. For the past 3 days, I have been working on this. I think my IQ is the same as that of a sloth. All I know is I changed the prefix coz in one of the tutorials the Youtuber said to change the prefix name if you have space in your username.

Comment: LOL don't worry, one day at a time. Post your code and the error message in one place and you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to update your npm version to 7.18.0.
Error is maybe due to npm version conflictions.